# Launching .bat from php gives me a error 'java' is not recognised

Tags: java, php, batch-file, exec

When launching the .bat with php i get this "java is not recognized as an internal or external command" but when just clicking on the .bat in windows it will launch fine. here is the code im using to launch the . bat

```
exec('START D:\http\ftp\vanilla-server\run.bat');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this (in your batch, for x32 Win):

```
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\%ProgramFiles%\java\jre7\bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Account that your web server is running at most likely does not set exact same environment variables like `PATH`, `JAVA_HOME`, etc... as your own account.

What can be done to fix it?

1. Change global PATH to include missing path to Java.
2. Change batch file to alter PATH to add missing path to Java in the very beginning.
3. Change batch file to use fully qualified path to Java

However, best approach is to refactor this. I would have PHP to write your intent to execute something into database, and have another background daemon or service pickup items from database and execute tasks when necessary. Today, your PHP script will be blocked until your batch file returns - not cool. It is also bad from security perspective - your web server has to have permission to execute commands, which makes it much easier to hack your web site.